# How do I specify timezone such that moment will give proper date for that timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Currently, the only date string I have back from a 3rd party api is `2015-12-22T19:00:00.000`

Its assumed to be 'America/New_York' timezone (EST).

but when I pass that to moment it is using my local time zone on my computer (PST).

I need to do math on moment date objects comparing two dates and this is messing up my calculations.

I tried doing this but its still giving me PST:

`moment('2015-12-22T19:00:00.000').tz('America/New_York')`

It should be 7PM est.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/ `var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");` --- you should use a constructor that uses timezone. Your code creates a time in your timezone then converts it to a specified timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using moment-timezone plugin...also @zerkms comment is correct.

```
const start_datetime_est = moment.tz('2015-12-22T19:00:00.000', 'America/New_York');
const end_datetime_est = moment(start_datetime_est).tz('America/New_York').add(3, 'hours');
```

You have to pass the ISO8601 date string as `moment.tz(str, zone)` -- I was doing `moment(str).tz(zone)` which was just giving me current time.

Comment: In the second line, the `tz` call is unnecessary.  The time zone from the original moment is carried forward during cloning.